# Reader and MonadReader

Tags: haskell, monads, reader-monad

Why is there a Reader monad and a MonadReader monad in Control.Monad.Reader? The package documentation talks about the Reader monad and then launches into the MonadReader documentation directly with no explanation. What is the difference between these monads? Reading these reference pages leaves me more than confused. Interestingly, the Reader monad page for the Haskell wikibook has yet to be written!

Comment: As I understand, this is an abstraction over anything which could behave like `Reader` monad. For example, it could be a stack of monad transformers. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no `MonadReader` monad. That is a *class* of monads, namely of those monads that can be *used as* a `Reader` (generally, because they're defined as a monad transformer stack with a [`ReaderT`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#t:ReaderT) in somewhere). So,

- [`Reader`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Reader.html#t:Reader) is the specific monad that *only* acts as a reader, because it has `ReaderT` only applied to the trivial identity monad:

  ```
  type Reader r = ReaderT r Identity
  ```

  It is thus obviously an instance of `MonadReader`, but doesn't do anything else.
- `MonadReader` is is the class of *all* monads that can read from some environment. Again, this includes `Reader` itself, but also `MaybeT (ReaderT Int (ListT IO))`.